# making GCM notifications configurable in applications

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

My question is

How to stop receiving notifications from GCM service with out using

```
  GCMRegistar.unregistar(context).
```

Is there any method to stop receiving notifications.

I need this because I want to make GCM Push Notification feature configurable by the user if user sets for getting notification he will receive notification otherwise stops receiving notification with out unregistering device

Any links helps me a lot.

Comment: with in getNotification function itself used sharedpreferences to find out whether user needs notification or not

Answer (score 0):

I do a similar thing with regards to my applications, if you get the paid version you get notifications, if you get the free version you don't get such updates.

I accomplished this by adding a field to the table where all my registration ID's are called status. When a notification push is done by my server it will only send to those registrations where the status is 'paid'.

So for your case I suggest adding the option to your application to stop receiving notifications. This method will perform a post to your server like follows:

```
Function updateNotificationStatus(boolean status)
{
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://yourserver/update.php");

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("status", status));

post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new 
}
```

Handle these posts on your server and just update the status field in you table.

Hope this helps

Comment: ya nicely done but my requirement is different i want to make it static means with in application user has choice to get notification thanks for posting

Comment: @Manju- You can't stop receiving the push once you register unless you hit GCMRegistar.unregistar(context) or app get uninstall, but one can stop showing the push base on configured state. If though the app receive the push message. Hope this helps you.